# Facebook API - Lista de produtos a venda em um grupo

Tags: facebook

Procurei na documentação e não encontrei, então como consigo obter a lista de produtos a venda em um grupo do Facebook, aqueles produtos que são postados na opção "Vender um item"?

Vi esses dois links, seria algum deles, ou é de outra forma?

1. [Marketing API Version - Product Group Products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-group/products/v3.0#Reading)
2. [Marketing API Version - Product Catalog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/v3.0)